# How could this difference in series of power of zeros associated to counting integers and counting primes be explained?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function, power-series

**Introduction:**

In [this 1992 paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1992-58-198/S0025-5718-1992-1122072-5/S0025-5718-1992-1122072-5.pdf), J.B. Keiper ([an amazing person](https://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/jerry-keiper/), who tragically died way too young), derives several power series expansions of the [Riemann $\xi$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function) that involve infinite sums of powers of the non-trivial zeros $\rho$ (taken in pairs).

$$\sigma_k= \sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho^k}$$

**Analogy:**

We know that the non-trivial zeros $\rho$ of $\zeta(s)$ drive the oscillating (error) term in the prime counting function(s). Analogously, the zeros $\mu = 0 \pm 2\pi n i$ induce the oscillating (sawtooth) behaviour in the [integer counting function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468334/an-integer-counting-function-nx). The entire function associated with the $\mu$'s is $\xi_i(s)=\frac{2}{s}\sinh\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)$. Now also define ($\mu$'s taken in pairs):

$$\hat{\sigma}_k= \sum_{\mu} \frac{1}{\mu^k} = \frac{\zeta(1-k)}{\Gamma(k)}$$

**Comparison:**

I found that all the expansions for $\xi(s)$ from Keiper's paper can be replicated for $\xi_i(s)$ and the results/relations are fully equivalent except for these three:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sigma_k}{k} &=0 \qquad \tag{Kei 16}\\
\sigma_1 &= -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sigma_k \qquad \tag{Kei 17}\\
\sigma_{j+1} &= (-1)^{j+1} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{k-1}{j}\sigma_k  \qquad \tag{Kei 18}
\end{align}
where in the latter series a $\sigma$ could be derived recursively. This recursion disappears in the equivalent series with the $\hat{\sigma}$'s:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\hat{\sigma}_k}{k} &=\ln\left(\frac{1}{{\rm e}-1}\right) \\
\frac{1}{{\rm e}-1} &= -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \hat{\sigma}_k \\
-1 + \frac{1}{\Gamma(j+1)} \sum_{k=0}^{j} \Gamma(j+1-k){j+1 \brace j+1-k} ({\rm e}-1)^{k-j-1} &= (-1)^{j+1} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{k-1}{j}\hat{\sigma}_k \\
\end{align}
where ${a \brace b}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).
**Question:**

Where could the differences in recursion between these series of $\sigma$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ originate from? I could conceive of two possible explanations:

- the functional equation $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$ versus $\xi_i(s) = \xi_i(-s)$ or
- some connection in the recursion of $\sigma$ to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

Or maybe there is a simpler rule at work here? Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: What do you mean by '$\sigma$ can be derived from series of $\sigma$'?  Is this just (Kei 18) restated?

Comment: @Stopple Yes it is.

Comment: It might be clearer to simply say that is is a recursion for the $\sigma$